# My Exoplayer player gives me an error when I use DASH

Tags: java, exoplayer2.x

```
06-26 12:32:30.141 16571-16980/com.example.dell.exoplayer_test E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @1:218 in java.io.InputStreamReader@c8b4a4f) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:105)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:58)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:130)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @1:218 in java.io.InputStreamReader@c8b4a4f) 
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1219)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1401)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:393)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:98)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:58) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:130) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my code line.

This metod is for initilizar the video

```
 private void initializePlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
    }
    prepareExoPlayer();
}
```

Here use DASH , I think maybe the problem is here

```
  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua",BANDWIDTH_METER);
    DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
    return new DashMediaSource
            (uri, dataSourceFactory, dashChunkSourceFactory, null, null);

}
```

Also prepare other metod but say the same error

```
  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua",BANDWIDTH_METER);
    DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
    return new DashMediaSource
            (uri, dataSourceFactory, dashChunkSourceFactory, null, null);
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? I researched other similar problems, but nothing similar to this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.